# Is energy distributed equally in system in thermodynamic equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, equilibrium

When a thermodynamic system is in equilibrium, it is said to have equally distributed energy, so that the entropy is highest possible, also, the temperature is same everywhere in the system. But considering objects of different heat capacities, wouldn't that be impossible? Since the average energy of a molecule is linear function of temparature with constant of proportiality x*R, where x is different for one(x=3/2), two(x=5/3) molecule gas or solid. And since temperature is the same and constants of proportion are different, average energy of molecules of objects with different heat capacities in system must be different.

Answer (score 1):

Thermodynamic equilibrium requires the *temperature* to be *uniform* throughout the system. What you call "equally distributed energy" is not a thermodynamic requirement but a special case when we are dealing with a single-phase system of a single component. Then it is true that the energy per molecule is the same under equilibrium.

In vapor/liquid equilibrium, on the other hand, the vapor has *more* energy per particle than the liquid, yet the system is in thermodynamic equilibrium. This again is because the uniformity of energy is not a requirement for equilibrium but a special condition that applies only in certain special cases.

Answer (score 1):

This answer takes a statistical physics approach, since in classical (equilibrium) thermodynamics, there is not really any way to talk about energy in different parts of the system.

For an isolated system, the system has a constant energy by definition.  "Equally distributed energy" doesn't really have any meaning here.

For two subsystems${}^*$ in contact (e.g., a "system" with a "reservoir"), but isolated from the rest of the universe, the pair may exchange energy.  At any moment, each subsystem has its own definite internal energy ($U_S$ and $U_R$, with $U_S + U_R = U_{\rm tot} =\text{ const}$). Each subsystem will have a certain number, $g$, of "microstates"/configurations available to it when it has a particular internal energy (you can think of this as the number of degenerate quantum states of the subsystem with that energy). The total number of configurations of the pair of subsystems is then
$$
g_{\rm tot} = \sum_{U_S} g_S\left(U_S\right) \, \cdot \, g_R\left(U_{\rm tot} - U_S\right)
$$
It turns out that for large systems, there is one term in that sum that overwhelmingly dominates, i.e., one value of energy that the system can take, $U_S = \hat{U}_S$, that contributes almost all of the $g_S \cdot g_R$ to the sum. Finding the maximum of the summand, when viewed as a function of $U_S$ and $U_R$, shows that this condition is:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial \log g_S}{\partial U_S}\right|_{\hat{U}_S} = \left.\frac{\partial \log g_R}{\partial U_R}\right|_{U_{\rm tot} - \hat{U}_S}
$$
where the log of the available microstates is called the entropy.  We define this condition to be "equilibrium", because it is extremely unlikely to see the pair of systems with an energy distribution that is far from it.  The thing that is equal in equilibrium --- the partial of entropy with respect to internal energy --- is therefore called the (inverse of the) temperature.

So the phrase "equal distribution of energy" doesn't really have meaning here either.  And having "entropy as high as possible" is actually a condition on the pair of systems (the particular energy sharing arrangement that you see, with overwhelming likelihood, is the one for which $g_S \cdot g_R$ is maximum).  You might be thinking of the *fundamental assumption of thermal physics*, which says that a system (or combination of systems) will be equally likely to be found in any of the microstates available to it.

[* --- This is the argument of Kittel & Kroemer]